# assigning AWS policies to a user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a policy and role I created for allowing lambda function to access couldWatch logging. however, the user account I've created (to let a developer write some lambda code) doesn't have the role showing when the user tries to add a lambda function.

The user's group is assigned the policy...

when logging into users account - I am seeing

```
user is not authorized to perform: kms:ListAliases on resource: *
```

But I cannot find a policy for kms

I think I got it - I added 
                "kms:ListAliases"
to Resources.*

Comment: Can you please show us the policy?

Comment: Please share more details like the policy, group, user & role associations.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow permission with "AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser", you can do

Comment: Please, explain it why.